# Creating Octomap from Blender file

Tags: ros, octomap, blender

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I would like to use dynamicEDT3D that comes with octomap for distance computation.
For the moment this question is not necessarily a ROS issue, but I hope to get an answer to my problem here as well.

I am using the latest source code from the octomap github repository and built it.
I created a simple environment within blender (2.61) only consisting of a wall spanning from 0,05..x..0,15 -0,5..y..0,5 0,0..z..1,0 (Blender coordinates) and a point lamp.
Then, I followed the [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/octomap/Tutorials/Creating%20an%20OctoMap%20from%20existing%203D%20%28mesh%29%20data) to generate a binary tree to initialize the octomap structure.

I used the following commands:

- Export as X3D Extensible 3D file with 'Y forward' and 'Z up'
- xsltproc -o collision_test_envYZ.vrml X3dToVrml97.xslt collision_test_envYZ.x3d

  [Info]  differs from computed profile='Interactive'
  [Hint] preferred Dublin Core Metadata Term is name='title' (vice filename) 
  [Hint] Recommended:  add  for documentation [check X3D source or VRML output to find pertinent head]
  [Hint] Recommended:  add  date content for documentation [check X3D source or VRML output to find pertinent head]
  [Hint] Recommended:  add  date content for documentation [check X3D source or VRML output to find pertinent head]
  [Warning] PointLight node location and radius are affected by translation and scaling of parent  [PointLight DEF='LA_Point']
- ./binvox64 -bb -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 -d 200 ~/octomap/data/collision_test_envYZ.vrml

  --- [binvox] mesh voxelizer, version 1.08, build #445 on 2011/08/02 18:49:00
  --- written by Patrick Min, 2004-2011

  ```
  will force bounding box to be [-1, -1, -1, 1] - [1, 1, 1, 1]
  ```

  loading model file...
  MeshFileIdentifier::*create_mesh_file(/home/fxm/octomap/data/collision_test_envYZ.vrml)
  VrmlMeshFile::load(/home/fxm/octomap/data/collision_test_envYZ.vrml)
  Timer [load_vrml] started
  VRML version 2.0
  75 lines read, and 4 top level nodes
  Mesh::add_def_name_group(Point_TRANSFORM, 0, -1, 0)
  Mesh::add_def_name_group(group_ME_Cube, 0, 5, 2)
  Mesh::add_def_name_group(Cube_ifs_TRANSFORM, 0, 5, 1)
  Mesh::add_def_name_group(Cube_TRANSFORM, 0, 5, 0)
  freeing VRML memory
  Timer [load_vrml] stopped at 0.000439 seconds
  bounding box: [0.05, -0.5, 0, 1] - [0.15, 0.5, 1, 1]
  normalization transform:
  (1) translate [-0.05, 0.5, -0, 1], (2) scale 1, (3) translate [0, 0, 0]
  removed 0 faces before rendering

  voxel model dimension: 200
  Graphics card and driver information:
  Vendor:   NVIDIA Corporation
  Renderer: GeForce GT 330M/PCI/SSE2
  Version:  3.3.0 NVIDIA 270.41.06
  Voxels::init(200, 200, 200)
  calling set clip box
  SimpleMeshView::set_clip_box
  Voxelizer::carve_voxelize
  doing x direction
  doing y direction
  doing z direction
  Voxelizer::parity_vote_voxelize
  doing x direction
  doing y direction
  doing z direction
  Voxels::process_votes
  Voxelizer::voxelize took 0.680941 seconds
  area filled: 20 x 200 x 200
  integer bounding box: [0,0,0] - [19,199,199]

  writing voxel file...
  VoxelFile::write_file(/home/fxm/octomap/data/collision_test_envYZ.binvox)
  Wrote 800000 set voxels out of 8000000, in 62748 bytes
  done
- ./binvox2bt --mark-free ../data/collision_test_envYZ.binvox

  Reading binvox file ../data/collision_test_envYZ.binvox.
  reading binvox version 1
  Generating octree with leaf size 0.005

  Read data: ....................

  read 800000 voxels, skipped 0 (out of bounding box)

  Pruning octree

  Writing octree to ../data/collision_test_envYZ.binvox.bt

  done

In the resulting binary tree, the bounding box of the binary tree is not [-1,-1,-1][1,1,1] as specified but appears to be something like [0.05,-0.5,0] - [1.05,0.5,1] (see octovis). Why is that? Did I do something wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52705/creating-octomap-from-blender-file/) by [Felix Messmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/208/felix-messmer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 198 on 2013-01-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2013-01-18**:
I agree that maybe ROS answers is not the best for issues related directly to OctoMap (not in ROS). If there is enough demand, I can create a mailing list or OctoMap-related questions and issues...

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2013-01-23**:
The new mailing list for OctoMap is here: https://groups.google.com/d/forum/octomap
This should be used in the future for general (non-ROS related) questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

binvox sometimes behaves strange, maybe it ignores the bounding box in a later step. As a first measure, I would get the latest version from [the author's homepage](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Emin/binvox/) (future versions of OctoMap will no longer contain binvox binaries anyways) and see if the problem is resolved with it.

I usually had good results with binvox using the -v or -e options, ignoring -bb. Instead, try using the --bb and --offset parameters of binvox2bt, that worked more reliable.

To verify whether the intermediate binvox file is OK you can use viewvox, and then octovis to verify the final .bt output.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0